# How to change implicit types in snakeyaml (int to double)

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

My yaml document looks similar to `seq: [0, 0.23, 0.45, 0.67]`

Snakeyaml parses the yaml sequence to an ArrayList with the values:

```
[0]: 0 (Integer)
[1]: 0.23 (Double)
[2]: 0.45 (Double)
[3]: 0.67 (Double)
```

I need all of these values to be of type `Double`, in order to convert the List to a `Double[]` using `list.toArray(new Double[])` - which throws an `ArrayStoreException` otherwise, because `Integer` is not the same type as `Double`.

1. Is there an acceptable way of converting an `ArrayList<Object>` to a `Double[]` that I missed?
2. How can I configure Snakeyaml to load all numbers as doubles?

---

### Additional Info

The Snakeyaml version used is 1.17.

I create the Snakeyaml instance like this:

```
private Yaml createYamlInstance() {
    DumperOptions dumperOptions = new DumperOptions();
    dumperOptions.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.AUTO);
    return new Yaml(dumperOptions);
}
```

---

### EDIT

I have looked at the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-implicit-types), but I can't see how the default implicit types are changed in the [example](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/tip/src/test/java/examples/resolver/CustomResolverTest.java?fileviewer=file-view-default).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation, the parsing of numbers is done by format:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#numbers

Perhaps changing the 0 to 0.00 will be sufficient.

Alternatively, if changing the format is impossible, perhaps you could cast the ArrayList members before use after the document was parsed?

Comment: Yes, but the document is generated beforehand and is much more conplex than the excerpt i provided in the question. therefore changing the document is not possible.

Comment: I see. If that's the case, is it possible to generate the document with the correct style rather than editing it after the fact?

Comment: That would be my last resort, if there really is no other option, as it would likely obscure the freemarker template (through which it is generated) a lot.

Comment: The other option could be simply casting it before use, since all integers will cause this issue (4.00 written as 4 will be parsed to Integer as well). So if you cannot prevent the format of numbers beforehand, you could simply use casting after the fact when accessing any specific ArrayList member.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove [INT implicit Resolver](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/391cdf1f1ee16267474b3b546d29d1fbd8c5e821/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Resolver.java-59).

Then the FLOAT implicit resolver will do the job.